# Why does this code output all the previous output rather than only the current iteration?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel api that I'm using to learn about buffers and I cannot seem to figure out why my outputs stack rather than give me only the current iteration. As an example the following code outputs the loop iteration count:

```
Route::post('test', function(Request $request) {
    echo "Begin ...\n";
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
    {
        echo $i . "\n";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    echo "End ...\n";
});
```

Here is the current output...

```
Begin ...

Begin ...
0

Begin ...
0
1

Begin ...
0
1
2
```

I'm looking to get the following...

```
begin ...

0

1

2
```

Is there a way to get the output to not include all previous iterations?

Comment: You're not destroying the output buffer content after flushing. It's therefore just getting appended to. Read about the [output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions.

Comment: Ah, okay I'll read the docs. Thanks for your help!